# Connection / Login Problemsof jitterbit data loader

Tags: data-migration, tools

When i am trying to login into jitter bit cloud dataloader with my sandbox username and passwerd i am getting an error `**"Agent is not Running[Agent-is-not- Running]"**`

Comment: Please try to find and use tags specific to your question.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this in the past and it's usually because the service is either not started or hung.

A) If you are on Windows, start the Jitterbit service

Windows: 
- Open the Services console from the Administrative Tools. 
- Locate the service Jitterbit Cloud Data Loader Tomcat Server. 
- If the status is not "Started", then start the service. 
- If the status is already "Started" then restart it.

B) IF you are on a Mac, launch the app called 'called "Jitterbit Cloud Data Loader Start Services".'
C) If you're on a Mac and it does not work,

- Run the application "Jitterbit Cloud Data Loader Stop Services".
- Then run the application "Jitterbit Cloud Data Loader Start Services".

This should fix it!

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work for me.